# Detailed view of cells in tableview?

Tags: image, swift, cells

Im trying to Give each cell a detailed view, this code gives each cell the one image colored red

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ViewTwo: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet weak var BandNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var BandPosterImage: UIImageView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    self.BandPosterImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Oh I apologize, I guess I wasn't even typing... I want to give each cell in the table detailed information.

Comment: @trevorj Yeah Idk why my original post was messed up.. But yes all the help is welcome.

Comment: Still not quite sure what you want to have happen. What do you mean you want to give each cell in the table detailed information? As in each cell should display information? Like text?

Comment: @trevorj yeah basically, Like check this snapshot. lets say my table is a bunch of cars.. If I click one info will appear http://www.techotopia.com/images/f/f7/Iphone_ios_5_table_View_storybaord_segue_running.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Drag out a new View Controller onto your storyboard and control-drag from your table view cell to that view controller. When prompted, under "Selection Segue" choose "Show." This creates a Push segue that automatically puts a back button on your next view controller's upper-lefthand corner (like in the image you included in your comment).

You can then design your view controller as you want in the interface builder and create a subclass of UIViewController to set up outlets and actions for that view controller (i.e. to handle any buttons, textfields, etc. that you may include). You can also pass any data that the second view controller will need in `prepareForSegue:` in your UITableViewController.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah that kind of helps, I was able to pass data and select each row and display info but the info is the same for all of them, do you know how I can assign each variable in the array different info? like do I need separate view controllers for all the different rows? (getting used to swift)

Comment: @NikolaBadnjar You definitely do not need separate view controllers for each! What you should do is create your own custom datatype. So, if you were showing car details, for example, you'd create a `Car` class with methods and instance variables (e.g. color, numOfSeats, numOfDoors, etc.) that describe cars. Then create an array of `Car` objects. In `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, you can determine which row and therefore which car in the `Car` array was selected and you can pass that `Car` to the next view controller in `prepareForSegue:` with something like `yourCarArray[indexPath.row]`